# Passing Options to Unknown Class

Tags: package-options, draft, class-options

My goal is to process a LaTeX tex file with the `draft` option enabled for the document class, but from a terminal without having to edit the tex file or even open it to look at what class is being used, given that I know it's a class which has the draft option. The option `pdflatex -draftmode` isn't what I'm looking for since it doesn't produce a pdf.

For example, suppose `main.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myfig}
\end{document}
```

Using `\documentclass[draft]{article}` should of course produce a box with the text "myfig.xxx" in it. The solution given to the question [Add option to class with command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74941/add-option-to-class-with-command) would almost be enough. I would use

```
pdflatex \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{article} \input{main}
```

But this isn't satisfactory since I have to know that the class is `article` rather than `book` or anything else.

As perhaps a second issue that might affect an answer; this solution doesn't even seem to entirely work given `article`, since it produces the image normally and not the box with its title inside. This surprises me since passing the option `12pt` in this manner seems to work properly. But I guess the option doesn't get passed through to `graphicx` or globally to other packages this way.

Comment: This might be something you want to do with a perl or sed script.  Would that meet your needs?

Comment: I'd welcome any working answer. A TeX only solution is ideal of course, but I'm not too picky. I run the commands through a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Document classes execute a number of "default" options via `\ExecuteOptions`. For example, [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) calls

```
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}
```

while [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) calls

```
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}
```

You could override and always pass `draft` to `\ExecuteOptions` using the following command-line "interface":

```
pdflatex \let\oldExecuteOptions\ExecuteOptions \def\ExecuteOptions#1{\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}} \input{main}
```

The above stores `\ExecuteOptions` in `\oldExecuteOptions` before redefining it to *always* end with the `draft` option.

Comment: Another nice thing about this is that it doesn't complain if `draft` is already specified with the document class in `main.tex`. `\ExecuteOptions` seems to have no problems with `draft` being there more than once.

Comment: @MarcusFontaine: Yes, however useless, there's no problem specifying `\documentclass[draft,draft,draft,draft,draft,draft]{article}` if you so wish. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perl script which will make a copy of your `main.tex` file and create a `formatted_main.tex` file which you can `LaTeX`.  It finds the `\documentclass` line and rewrites it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($filehandle) = @ARGV;
open FILEHANDLE, "<$filehandle" or die "cannot open < $filehandle: $!";
my @file = <FILEHANDLE>;
close FILEHANDLE;

foreach my $line ( @file )
  {
    if ( $line =~ /^\s*\\documentclass\[/ )
     {
       $line =~ s/(\\documentclass)(\[)/$1$2draft,/;
     }
    if ( $line =~ /^\s*\\documentclass{/ )
     {
       $line =~ s/(\\documentclass)({)/$1\[draft\]$2/;
     }
  }

open FILE, ">formatted_$filehandle";
foreach my $line ( @file ){
   print FILE $line;
 }
close FILE;
```

*UPDATE*

One problem with this script is that it expects that whoever wrote `main.tex` did not split the `\documentclass` macro from its arguments.  In other words, this script will not help you if `main.tex` contains a line like

```
\documentclass
    [12pt]{article}
```

If you're concerned that this might be a possibility, then I would definitely go with @Werner 's solution.

Comment: The tex files I work with can have odd things going on with them, like you've keenly pointed out. Thank you for making this answer though.